# Does Linux validate ELF signatures?

Tags: linux, elf, signing

I see that ELF binaries can be signed. Can Linux Kernel enforce validation of ELF signinatures for kernel modules and user mode binaries?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: *"Can Linux Kernel enforce validation of ELF signatures..."* - You probably need to use a kernel like Gentoo. Also take a look at PaX enabled kernels.